# How to calculate with numbers in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting to subtract some values of inputs with the total price.

The code:

```
$('.calculate-resterend').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var contant = $('.checkout-contant').val();
    var pin = $('.checkout-pin').val();
    var creditcard = $('.checkout-creditcard').val();
    var waardebon = $('.checkout-waardebon').val();

    var totalprice = $('.total.final-price.price').text();
    alert(contant - totalprice);
});
```

But this returns `NaN`. I figure it's because total price is `.text();`,
but what is the correct way to substract between these things.

Lets say `var contant` has a value of `2000,98`
and the `total price` has a value of `2400,99`

I want it to return `400,01`.

Comment: `$('.checkout-contant')[0].val();` first of all, or use ID if you have one of those

Comment: `.val()` and `.text()` return a string, you've to parse them. @RápliAndrás your code will return an error, because `.val()` function does not exist in the element context.

Comment: Do your values actually have the comma?  If so I would suggest removing that, then covert to a number, do your calculations, and then format the results as you see fit.

Comment: @Jordi, is your input Localized?

Comment: So I understand this code calculates a price in a webshop...on clientside?

Comment: Not for a webshop, for a cash register. It will later be also verified by php, this is only for displaying @CasparKleijne

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Number()`

```
alert(Number(contant) - Number(totalprice));
```

If you also want to remove comman(,)

```
alert(Number(contant.replace(/\,/g,'')) - Number(totalprice.replace(/\,/g,'')));
```

Comment: This still returns NaN.

Comment: I guess comma is used to represent decimal value as `2000,99` is incorrect currency format. It should have been `200,099`

Comment: This works, although i had to replace the , with a dot. You forget that in your answer, thank you for this!

Comment: Accept the answer it it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to convert one of your values using parseInt. You can try the following:

totalprice = parseInt(totalprice)

And then proceed to do your simple subtraction like before. You could also try to make your own price attribute on the HTML element itself and the fetch the attribute value instead like .attr("price"). Not sure if that would return a string as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert your value by using parseint()

eg:-   parseint(your_value)